# WPF ListView not caching images

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that uses a `ListView` with a grid that displays images directly from the web. When the list is populated the images load as expected, but as I scroll down (the list contains around 200 items on average) it starts reusing the items that aren't in view (as it should). However, this causes the images to be released from memory and as a result they get reloaded all over again when the user scrolls back up.

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<ListView Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}" Background="{StaticResource PrimaryBackground}" Foreground="{StaticResource PrimaryForeground}"
              ui:GridViewSort.AutoSort="True" ui:GridViewSort.ShowSortGlyph="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="80">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Foo}">
                                <Image>
                                    <Image.Source>
                                        <BitmapImage CacheOption="OnDemand" UriSource="{Binding PreviewImageUrl}" />
                                    </Image.Source>
                                </Image>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" ui:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Title" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Remix" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Remix}" ui:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Remix" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Artist" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artist}" ui:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Artist" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Duration" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Duration}" ui:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Duration" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="BPM" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Bpm}" ui:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Bpm" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Year" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}" ui:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Date" />
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,10,0" />
                                        </Style>
                                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                                    <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=DataContext.Download}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">Download</Button>
                                    <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=DataContext.CopyLink}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">Copy link</Button>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Setting the `Image.Source` property with a different `CacheOption` makes no difference. You can also see I disabled virtualization which is bad but it's the only way to have it keep the images in memory. Is there an easy way to stop this from happening while also enabling virtualization?

Comment: You would need to handle the images your self, there is no out of the box functionality for that, or at least I don't know of any. SO maybe you can change your model and pre download the images and store them in your model objects, then you don't need to handle anything. You'll have your images in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Add a readonly `PreviewImage` property to your search results item class that creates and holds the BitmapImage when it is first accessed:

```
public class SearchResult : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Uri previewImageUrl;
    public Uri PreviewImageUrl
    {
        get { return previewImageUrl; }
        set
        {
            previewImageUrl = value;
            previewImage = null;

            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(PreviewImageUrl));
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(PreviewImage));
        }
    }

    private ImageSource previewImage;
    public ImageSource PreviewImage
    {
        get
        {
            if (previewImage == null && previewImageUrl != null)
            {
                previewImage = new BitmapImage(previewImageUrl);
            }

            return previewImage;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

and bind to it like this:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding PreviewImage}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Image 
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions ="CenterAndExpand">
    <Image.Source>
        <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding Image}" 
            CacheValidity="14" 
            CachingEnabled="true"/>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: This is not available in WPF.